# Declaring variable and assigning value for re-usability in oracle

Tags: oracle

In `Oracle` I need to use ID in several tables to update the value, I am trying to get value like below, and then assigning to a variable and then trying to use, but I am getting an error

```
declare myVal varchar2;
BEGIN
    begin
    myVal := select ID from USER where USER_NUMBER = 53;
    end;
Update myOtherTable1 SET VAL = myVal;
Update myOtherTable2 SET VAL = myVal
Update myOtherTable3 SET VAL = myVal
Update myOtherTable4 SET VAL = myVal
Update myOtherTable5 SET VAL = myVal
...........
END
```

Error

> ORA-06550: line 4, column 14: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol
>   "SELECT" when expecting one of the following:
>
> ( - + case mod new not null          continue avg count current
>   exists max min prior sql stddev    sum variance execute forall merge
>   time timestamp interval    date       pipe

Comment: select ID into myVal from ...

Answer (score 1):

You need:

```
DECLARE
    myVal    VARCHAR2(100); -- you need a size
BEGIN
    BEGIN
        SELECT ID
          INTO myVal
          FROM USER
         WHERE USER_NUMBER = 53;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
        THEN
            ...
        WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS
        THEN
            ...
    END;

    UPDATE myOtherTable1
       SET VAL    = myVal;

    ...
END;
```

I added some exception handling here, it's up to you to decide if you need it, what to do, ....

A different way, with SQLPlus and with no PL/SQL could be like :

```
SQL> variable myVal varchar2;
SQL> select 1 into :myval from dual;

         1
----------
         1

SQL> update someTable set n = :myval;
```